# Ruby - digest authentication for soap and byte arrays

Tags: ruby, soap, digest, digest-authentication

How do I convert string or a value to a byte array? 
I need it for SOAP authentication. My requirement is to -
On the client side, this is how to create a digest:
1.  Client Side Digest Array = byte array nonce + byte array UTC date-time of UTF-8 string + byte array UTF-8 plain text password (concatenate these three).
2.  Client Side SHA-1 Digest = Hash with SHA-1 algorithm the Client Side Digest Array.
3.  Client Side WS-Security Digest = 64-bit encode the Client Side SHA-1 Digest

Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + timestamp + password ) )

This is the code I am using to generate nonce, timestamp and digest_password. User password is a string. Some ting is wrong in the whole process and my digest is not successfully generated. I guess I have these data types right, byte array and UTF8 is confusing me. 
I added utf8 conversion but no difference.

```
def nonce
   chars = ("a".."z").to_a + ("1".."9").to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a
   @nonce = Array.new(20, '').collect{chars[rand(chars.size)]}.join
end

def timestamp
    t = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")
    @timestamp = t.to_s
end

def digest_password

ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'US-ASCII')
$time =  ic.iconv( timestamp + ' ')[0..-2]
$pass =  ic.iconv( password + ' ')[0..-2]
temp = (nonce.bytes.to_a + $time.bytes.to_a + $pass.bytes.to_a)
@digest_password = Base64.strict_encode64(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(temp.to_s))

###  temp =  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(nonce + timestamp + password) ##old    
###@digest_password = Base64.encode64(temp) ##old

end


    <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="http://xml.myserver.com/ok/service/v1_5" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
       <wsse:Security env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
       <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
       <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">YWIwM2QyZWI3YTEwMTAzZmNkNmZiNmEwMjg1ODlkOTU0OTNmNmUxYQ==
       </wsse:Password> 
       <wsse:Nonce>ZEUyQ2J6bmw5cjdDZmt1QjVqTjQ=</wsse:Nonce>
       <wsu:Created>2012-03-27T11:08:35.125Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able to solve this issue.

```
Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + create + password) )
```

`nonce` = nonce as string. Before Base64 endoce, E.g "1234"

`create` = time as string. No encoding

`password` = password as string. No encoding.

`Base64Nonce` = `Base64.encode64(nonce).strip` #Base64 encode of "1234"

```
chars = ("a".."z").to_a + ("1".."9").to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a
nonce = Array.new(20, '').collect{chars[rand(chars.size)]}.join

t = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")

$time = t
$pass = p
Base64Nonce = Base64.encode64(nonce).strip 

$digest_pass = Base64.encode64(Digest::SHA1.digest(nonce + $time + $pass)).strip



          "wsse:Username" => username,
          "wsse:Password" => $digest_pass,
          "wsse:Nonce" => Base64Nonce,
          "wsu:Created" => $time,
```

Comment: For the time there is a easier way: `require 'time'; Time.now.utc.iso8601(3)`

Answer (score 0):

Is it right to `Base64.encode` in the `nonce` method and then `Base64.encode` again in the `digest_password` method? Seems strange for me. Maybe you should do

```
def nonce
   chars = ("a".."z").to_a + ("1".."9").to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a
   @nonce = Array.new(20, '').collect{chars[rand(chars.size)]}.join
end
```

Comment: Padde, Fixed that, but made no difference.